# Get email address with Xamarin.Auth and Facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, xamarin, oauth-2.0

I have the following code to try connect the authenticator

```
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
            appId,
            "email",
            new Uri ("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
            new Uri ("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));
```

and when the dialog shows, I can see that it is requesting permission to see my email. But how do I get that email from the service?

I make the following call to get the Facebook ID

```
var request = new OAuth2Request ("GET", new Uri ("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, args.Account);
                request.GetResponseAsync ().ContinueWith (t => {
                    var obj = JsonValue.Parse (t.Result.GetResponseText ());
                    var id = obj ["id"];
                });
```

But there is no email in the reponse that I get back. How can I get the email address of the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lastest API version (2.4 at time of writing) uses Declarative Fields, so you need to explicitly request the email field like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email

Comment: Hi, I am using this link with fields=email, but it did not return email Id. Here is my link https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?access_token=CAAN8FxOdoyABAB3gBzOTyzoqDzBtvrZCcx90F98lyNdOrZCNZAmmpS8yQiHpN8cWq1cufmzPZCRpBRiY6fAYE98VaETN2MdEziTnK97TTptUwCKbTf0s4glWohInyorZBx9BjTyi8qrRqCpRrLdsoygWZA3v6HUhCPg6OCmQhjSI619raeqshqj4VzQ5Lr7X4ZD&fields=email   Please suggest.